# C# create earthmap dictionary of latitudes and longitudes with distance 100km

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure math for getting all longitudes and latitudes in a specific distance between each other. I have math for getting distance between geographic coords but I would like to get an array of all geo coords from the standard plane earthmap in the specific distance. Can you help me, please?

Here is example [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi3r87E5fPmAhXK7eAKHZqABcQQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisibleearth.nasa.gov%2Fimages%2F73580%2Fjanuary-blue-marble-next-generation-w-topography-and-bathymetry&psig=AOvVaw23gbkbHlQNkkkm_PGHC9sD&ust=1578565674814374) of earthmap picture. I have earth heightmap in resolution 43200x21600 and I would like to get heights/pixels indexed from bottom left to top right in exact distance 100km. If I can get longitudes and latitudes in distance 100km then I can read these heights.

Here is math for distance between geographic points:

```
public static float GetGeographicDistance(float latitudeA, float longitudeA, float latitudeB, float longitudeB, float earthRadius = 6371.007f)
        {
            float phi1 = latitudeA * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            float phi2 = latitudeB * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            float deltaPhi = (latitudeB - latitudeA) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            float deltaLambda = (longitudeB - longitudeA) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            float a = Mathf.Sin(deltaPhi / 2) * Mathf.Sin(deltaPhi / 2) +
                Mathf.Cos(phi1) * Mathf.Cos(phi2) *
                    Mathf.Sin(deltaLambda / 2) * Mathf.Sin(deltaLambda / 2);
            float c = 2.0f * Mathf.Atan2(Mathf.Sqrt(a), Mathf.Sqrt(1.0f - a));

            return earthRadius * c;
        }
```

Comment: is the array supposed to be points(b) with a x distance from point(a)? or is it supposed to be a list of all possible points(a) and points(b)?

Comment: It can be Dictionary<Vector2, int> where Vector.x is latitude and Vector.y is longitude. Int is index. Index 0 starts bottom left which is lat -90 lon -180, Index 1 should have lat and lon calculated +100km from previous index coords.

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.catalina-capri-25s.org/tech/latlongcalc.asp
The chapter 'Destination point given distance and bearing from start point' will help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much.....it is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Got it. If somebody needs it, here is the function in C#.

```
public static TGeographicCoordinate DestinationPointFromStartPoint(TGeographicCoordinate start, double distance = 100f, double bearing = 90f, double earthRadius = 6371.009d)
        {
            TGeographicCoordinate result = new TGeographicCoordinate();
            double angularDistanceRdn = distance / earthRadius;
            double bearingRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * bearing;

            double startLatRad = start.Latitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            double startLonRad = start.Longitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            result.Latitude = Math.Asin((Math.Sin(startLatRad) * Math.Cos(angularDistanceRdn)) +
                      (Math.Cos(startLatRad) * Math.Sin(angularDistanceRdn) * Math.Cos(bearingRad)));
            result.Longitude = startLonRad + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(bearingRad) * Math.Sin(angularDistanceRdn) * Math.Cos(startLatRad),
                                         Math.Cos(angularDistanceRdn) - (Math.Sin(startLatRad)) * Math.Sin(result.Latitude));

            result.Latitude *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            result.Longitude *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            return result;
        }
```